# How to print SQL variable to UNIX bash command line

Tags: sql, bash, wp-cli

Want to print the value of a variable I create.

```
    SET @count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'wordpress');

    PRINT @count + 1;
```

The above code is saved into a file called count-new.sql.

I execute the above code using the following WP-CLI (a command line for WordPress) code:

```
    sudo wp db query < count-new.sql --allow-root
```

And receive the following error:
        ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 3: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your...

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I understood from [documentation](http://wp-cli.org/commands/db/query/) that .sql file must containt only the query